# реализовать slider, который меняет слайдеры в зависимости от времени суток

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно реализовать слайдер, который меняет слайды каждые 45 сек, чтобы при входе на сайт, пользователь видел не первый слайд, а тот который должен быть выведен в зависимости от времени. Есть идеи как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

ну если идея,то:

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
if (hour < 12){
    // morning
    // ... удалить\добавить класс active для определенного слайдера
} else if (hour > 16){
    // evening
    // ... удалить\добавить класс active для определенного слайдера
}
```

Comment: если будет 15 слайдеров, то слишком много условий, больше вариантов нет

Comment: *каждые 45 сек*

Comment: Alex, а если каждые 3 секунды, нужно менять,  слайдов всего 15

Comment: @lesha310392, берёте текущее время и делите его на Ваши периоды.